# JQuery doesn't load HTML file (in Bootstrap template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

Trying to load Bootstrap nav with jQuery. It doesn't work...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
     $("#nav").load("nav.html");
   });
</script>  
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="nav">
  </nav>
```

And here is `nav.html` - simplified version. And it's not loaded.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: yep
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:20)
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)

Comment: try replacing your JS with this `$(document).ready(() => { $("#nav").load("nav.html"); })`

Comment: Same error...
also get this warning
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).load is not a function TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/andriigorokhovskyi/MyProject/andrii1.github.io/index.html:19:49)
    at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307) undefined

Comment: @AndriiGorh Did you try to put your `jQuery script` at the beginning of your code on the top?

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap this into `$(document).ready(function() { ...yourFunction... });` so that it's executed *after* the rest of the doc is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

So, seems found the issue. I'm using Bootstrap template, where jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js file is included - which **disables Ajax**.

Instead I replaced it with full jQuery version:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

And now .load seems to work.